# Is there a syntax to define inheritence inside of class definitions in PlantUML?

Tags: uml, plantuml

For class diagrams, the examples I've seen look like

```
class A{
  [snip] list of class features
} 
class B{
  [snip] list of class features
}

A <|-- B
```

i.e. the inheritance arrow is explicitly called out.

Is there a valid synax where I can just say something like:

```
class A{
} 
class B: public A {
}
```

and automatically getting the inheritance arrow in the resulting diagram?

Comment: I don't know what exactly [plantuml](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/qa/) can do and what are your reasons why you want/need to use it. But: there are tools capable of reverse engineering real-life code into UML class diagrams from real-life languages including C++, Java, PHP, C#... with inheritance, attributes, methods.. you can try following query to find some related off-topic Stack Overflow articles: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uml+reverse+engineer+class+diagram

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Both inheritance and interface implementation are supported.

```
class A extends B
class C implements D
```

However, the members are not duplicated in the classes. It simply takes care of the relationship arrow.